# Where to put global "filters" after filters are removed in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have a utils/filters.js file with lots of string helpers, but here's a short example:

```js
const filters = [
  {
    name: 'twitterLink',
    filter: (username) => {
      return `https://twitter.com/${username}`;
    }
  },
];

export default filters;
```

And I import it into main.js before initialising my app:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import filters from './utils/filters';

filters.forEach(f => {
  Vue.filter(f.name, f.filter)
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

So that I can use it in any component, anywhere in the app, without having to import it:

```html
<a :href="user.twitterUsername | twitterLink">
  {{ user.twitterUsername | twitterLink }}
</a>
```

What'd be the best way to replace these global filters when [filters are removed in Vue 3](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/97)?

Comment: why don't you just import them and use them like functions?

Comment: I'd like to import them just once in main.js (or wherever's appropriate) so that I don't have to repeatedly import them everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `provide`, `inject` to provide your filters globaly and inject them when needed into your components.

E.g.:

```
import filters from "@/utils/filter

const App = {
   provide: function(){
     return {
       filter1: method,
       filter2: method,
       ...,
       ...filters.reduce((obj, entry)=>obj[entry.name]=entry.filter, {}),
       filterN: method

     }
   },
   setup(){...}
}
```

and in another component:

```
const comp = {
   inject: ["filer1", "filterN", "twitterLink"],
   ...,
   computed:{
      twitterLinksFromUsers(){
        return this.users.map(this.twitterLink);
      }
   }
}
```

for the templates your have to drop the pipe `|` and invoke those methods.

If you want to access the filter with `this.filter[filterName]` just `provide(){return {filter:{...filters}}`

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

I know you said you don't want to have to import each item individually, but I would suggest you do just that, for a few reasons:

1. You don't have to lookup Vue's filter documentation to understand how it works. It's super explicit where the functions are coming from and how they are implemented.
2. The functions themselves are just JavaScript. You can alter/compose them to fit special uses cases unlike built-in filters which you cannot touch.
3. You can import and programmatically reuse these functions in methods, computed properties and anywhere you write JavaScript.

### Alternatives (not recommended)

#### Attach them to Vue.prototype

```js
Vue.prototype.filters = {
  someFilter: ...,
  anotherFilter: ...
}
```

```html
<ul v-for="word in filters.someFilter(words, userInput)">
  <li>{{word}}</li>
</ul>
```

#### Go functional (advanced)

```js
computed: {
  filteredThings () {
    return this.things
       .filter(contains(this.foo))
       .sort(by(thing => thing.bar))
       .slice(0, 10)
  }
}
```

Where the helper functions look like:

```js
// a function that returns a predicate function for array.filter()
function contains (value) {
  return thing => thing.indexOf(value) > -1
}

function by (getValue) {
  return (a, b) => {
    return getValue(a) > getValue(b) ? 1 : -1
  }
}
```

### Final thoughts

**Again, a very important design consideration is that built-in filters can be useful, but they lack the flexibility of pure JavaScript**.